# chromedriver version (116.0.5845.187) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome (117.0.5938.62)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

The chromedriver version (116.0.5845.187) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (117.0.5938.62); currently, chromedriver 117.0.5938.62 is recommended for chrome 117.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/main.py", line 8, in <module>

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in _*init*_

super()._*init*_(

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in _*init*_

super()._*init*_(

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in _*init*_

self.start_session(capabilities)

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session

response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute

self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "/home/lenovo/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Stacktrace:

#0 0x5578c5d97bf3 <unknown>

#1 0x5578c5ad26a7 <unknown>

#2 0x5578c5afaef9 <unknown>

#3 0x5578c5af9a19 <unknown>

#4 0x5578c5b398a1 <unknown>

#5 0x5578c5b38eef <unknown>

#6 0x5578c5b309f3 <unknown>

#7 0x5578c5b04c32 <unknown>

#8 0x5578c5b059de <unknown>

#9 0x5578c5d5c82d <unknown>

#10 0x5578c5d610a7 <unknown>

#11 0x5578c5d6a4e8 <unknown>

#12 0x5578c5d61ae0 <unknown>

#13 0x5578c5d3280e <unknown>

#14 0x5578c5d82568 <unknown>

#15 0x5578c5d8275a <unknown>

#16 0x5578c5d9120a <unknown>

#17 0x7f9f564adb43 <unknown>

Process finished with exit code 1

I Have installed the chromdriver( `117.0.5938.62` (`r1181205`)) and chrome version 117.0.5938.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)  but I am getting the above error

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.executable_path = '/home/len/jss/Configuration/chrome-linux64/chrome'#excutable path in linux

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')

search_box.submit()

time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

driver.quit()
```